# Createoperation concept not clear (RBAC)

Tags: php, yii, rbac

i just read about creating operation for defining the authorization rules...there was a code in the book which is as follows

```
# protected/controllers/SiteController.php::actionSetup()
$auth = Yii::app()->authManager;
$auth->createOperation('createPage',"create a new page");
$auth->createOperation('updatePage',"update a page");
```

The first argument is the identifier that specifies the operation uniquely...second is the description of the operation....

**NOW my QUESTION is**

where is the **ACTION** attached to the operation..it just consists of the name and the description...?? Even if i assign this operation to a user....how will the rule identify that which action has been assigned to it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the auth manager assign function to give users access to an auth item. 
See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/IAuthManager#assign-detail

E.g.

```
Yii::app()->authManager->assign('createPage', $idOfMyUser);
```

You can then use the access rules in a controller to control who can perform an action

Like:

```
   public function accessRules()
   {
         array('allow',
            'actions' => array('create'),
            'roles' => array('createPage')),        
         array('deny'),
      );
   }
```

Note that Roles, Operations and Tasks are essentially the same thing, they are just a ways of seperating or groping auth items

Comment: actually sir what you told me is really helpful but i am asking that $auth->createOperation('createPage',"create a new page"); the **createpage** is the name of this operation i have made....or it is the name of the action i have made in the controllor....what is this **createpage** here???

Comment: It is the name of the operation (AuthItem) that you use to check access.

Comment: Yii::app()->authManager->assign('createPage', 'public'); If i have an action **dothis** and i want it to assign it to the **public** with the help of operation...Do i need to attach **dothis** action to **createpage** operation first and then assign it to the **public**???